# How to decompress an AES-256 Encrypted zip files? 

Tags: java, android, zip, compression, aes

I am developing an android application which requires to decompress an **AES-256** encrypted zip files, is there any libraries out there that I can use to accomplish that?

I am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using an external library at http://code.google.com/p/winzipaes/

it's limited to compression/decompression Zip files encrypted with AES-256 **ONLY**

but at least it fits my need.

Answer (score 8):

**zip4j**, java library to handle Zip files (Open source, Apache License v2.0).

http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/

- Create, Add, Extract, Update, Remove files from a Zip file
- Read/Write password protected Zip files
- Supports AES 128/256 Encryption
- Supports Standard Zip Encryption

You can download binary, sources and examples.

Comment: its amazing I wish I have founded before I already ported  http://www.artpol-software.com/ZipArchive/ into android using ndk thanks a lot for the share

Answer (score 1):

It depends on you encoding of encrypted zip files. Be more specific please.
If its compress then encrypt then you decompress then decrypt the file using [java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer but in my question it's clear that i need to "decompress Encrypted zip files" i will update my Q, thanks a lot.

Comment: I fully understand, however this 'encrypted zip file' using a specific format, how is it encrypted? ECB, CBC, CTR or ...? Is the zip file an archive? Who generates the file? How is it generated? etc... Then I could post you a code to use.

Comment: thanks for the response, the encrypted zip file that i am trying to decompress is an archive and encrypted using AES-256 built through other windows application which i will download it on an Android device and do the decompression to read it's content.

Comment: Find a library then, otherwise it a huge task since those archives allow for different modes of operations and different AES-256 algorithms for chaining and padding!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember AES encrypted ZIP files were introduced some years the first time by WinZip.
On the WinZip home page there is a detailed explanation how the AES encrypted ZIP files differs from a standard ZIP file:

http://www.winzip.com/aes_info.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link, i have had implemented the Decompression on Zip File encrypted with AES-256 on iPhone and i know exactly how it works but for now i am stuck with android implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a normal JRE. Using http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/ the following code works to decrypt a zip file:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFile);
zipFile.setPassword(password);
for (Object fileHeaderObj : zipFile.getFileHeaders()) {
  FileHeader fileHeader = (FileHeader) fileHeaderObj;
  String fileName = fileHeader.getFileName();
  ZipInputStream zipIn = zipFile.getInputStream(fileHeader);
  // do whatever with the input stream
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I face a similar problem and searched a lot and tested all these solutions but they didn't help me.
Finally, I found a solution and I want to share it here maybe it can help others.

In my case, I have a AES-256 Encrypted zip file.

When I used the last version of zip4j, I faced this exception:

> Zip4j does not support Strong Encryption

zip4j code:

```
    net.lingala.zip4j.ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("sourceAddress", "password".toCharArray());
    zipFile.extractAll("destinationAddress");
```

After that I tested winzipaes and I faced this error:

> extra field is of length 0 - this is probably not a WinZip AES encrypted entry

winzipaes code:

```
    final File dbFile = new File("destinationFile");
    AesZipFileDecrypter ze = null;
    try {
        ze = new AesZipFileDecrypter(new File("sourceAddress"), new AESDecrypterBC());
        ExtZipEntry entry = ze.getEntry(dbFile.getName());
        ze.extractEntry(entry, dbFile, "password");
    } catch (DataFormatException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ze != null) {
            try {
                ze.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, I find sevenzipjbind and it works for me.

Final code:

```
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = null;
    IInArchive inArchive = null;
    try {
        randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(fileAddress, "r");
        inArchive = SevenZip.openInArchive(null, // autodetect archive type
                new RandomAccessFileInStream(randomAccessFile));

        // Getting simple interface of the archive inArchive
        ISimpleInArchive simpleInArchive = inArchive.getSimpleInterface();

        System.out.println("   Hash   |    Size    | Filename");
        System.out.println("----------+------------+---------");

        for (ISimpleInArchiveItem item : simpleInArchive.getArchiveItems()) {
            final int[] hash = new int[] { 0 };
            if (!item.isFolder()) {
                ExtractOperationResult result;

                result = item.extractSlow(new ISequentialOutStream() {
                    public int write(byte[] data) throws SevenZipException {
                        InputStream myInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

                        try {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[myInputStream.available()];
                            myInputStream.read(buffer);
                            File targetFile = new File(destinationAddress + item.getPath());
                            OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
                            outStream.write(buffer);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return data.length; // Return amount of consumed data
                    }
                },password);

                if (result == ExtractOperationResult.OK) {
                    System.out.printf("%9X | %s%n",
                            hash[0], item.getPath());
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Error extracting item: " + result);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error occurs: " + e);
    } finally {
        if (inArchive != null) {
            try {
                inArchive.close();
            } catch (SevenZipException e) {
                System.err.println("Error closing archive: " + e);
            }
        }
        if (randomAccessFile != null) {
            try {
                randomAccessFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error closing file: " + e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't have tested it yet, but some time ago I found [this](http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/39/index.html).

I hope it can help you

Comment: Thanks maid450 but this is not what i am looking for, this is Encrypt/Decrypt Strings, i need Encrypt/Decrypt Zip files, thanks for the effort.