# Can a zip file be encrypted with AES

Tags: java, encryption, compression, password-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I am new to encryption process. Can a zip file be encrypted with a given text or can we encrypt the zip by any algorithm like aes, triples aes, blowfish. If there is a process, please guide me with examples and reference.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.winzip.com/aes_info.htm) what you are looking for ?

Comment: is there any Opensource

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decompress an AES-256 Encrypted zip files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584775/how-to-decompress-an-aes-256-encrypted-zip-files)

Comment: AES is an algorithm for [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) encryption, while asymmetric encryption is related to public-private-key schemes. Could you explain what you meant with AES Asymmetric, is it just a typo?

Answer (score 2):

> zip4j, java library to handle Zip files (Open source, Apache License
>   v2.0).
>
> http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/
>
> Create, Add, Extract, Update, Remove files from a Zip file Read/Write
>   password protected Zip files Supports AES 128/256 Encryption Supports
>   Standard Zip Encryption You can download binary, sources and examples.

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584775/how-to-decompress-an-aes-256-encrypted-zip-files) is likely to solve your issues. I founded also the [java.util.zip documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) which might help you.

I also have heard once about [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) being linkable into a project, but I don't know if it is possible in java.

Comment: zip4j has moved to Github. https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j